# Assigning a variable during arithmetic in Java?

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic, java-17

My professor gave us this java snippet during a lecture and I don't understand why it outputs 12.

```
int b = 9; 
b = b + (b = 3); 
System.out.println( "b = " + b );
```

My thinking is that since parentheses give operations precedence, `b` would be reassigned to 3 first. Then, it would go `b = 3 + 3 = 6`. Obviously, this isn't the case and `b = 9 + 3 = 12` is actually executed. Why is the code executed left to right and not parentheses first?

Excuse my poor title, I'm not sure what to call this because I don't think you ever actually program this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence does not mean that it runs *first*. It merely lets you rewire operator precedence. Ordinarily something like `1 + 2 * 3` is resolved as:

- A plus operation between A and B, where
- A is the integer literal '1'
- B is the expression `2 * 3`.

Why? Because operator precedence rules state that * binds tighter than +. With parens you can override that; `(1 + 2) * 3` is a multiply operation between A and B where B is a '3' literal and A is '1 + 2'. That's all it does. It doesn't change the order in which things are resolved.

Java first evaluates 'b' (it's 9), then it evaluates (b = 3) (which is 3, and as a side effect, makes b become 3), and thus that expression is 12, which is then assigned to b, so it's 12.

Why does it evaluate the left hand side of that `+` first? Because the spec says so: resolves left to right.

Try this for funsies:

```
int b = 9;
b = (b = 3) + b;
System.out.println(b);
```

*now* it prints 6 as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The entire expression on the right hand side is evaluated before the value of `b` is then changed.  Also, it is evaluated from left to right.  So the value of `b` does change during the evaluation of the expression, but the first `b` has already been sampled as `9` before the second term sets `b` to 3.  It doesn't matter that `b` is eventually being set to the result of the expression.  The term `(b = 3)` has the value `3`.  So the assignment is just:

```
b = 9 + 3
```

And so the result you get is `12`.

On the other hand, the statement:

```
b = (b = 3) + b;
```

simplifies to

```
b = 3 + 3
```

Resulting in `6`.  This occurs because, again, the expression is evaluated left to right.  So the first term has a value of `3` and also sets `b` to `3` before the second term `b` is then evaluated, and so has a value of `3`.

Comment: But why is the right-hand side evaluated before the value of b is changed? Don't the parentheses mean that b=3 is executed first which should also change the value of the first b? If I also have a=3 and do b = b * (b + a), (b+a) is executed before b is multiplied with the other value.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I just clarified it all for you.  It's the order of evaluation that makes the big difference here.

Comment: @S.King the parentheses do not change the precedence in this case. In case of `a * (b + c)`, the parentheses ensure that it is not interpreted as `(a * b) + c`. However, in the case of `a + (b = c)`, there is no alternative interpretation, as `(a + b) = c` wouldn’t work at all. The parentheses are required to make embedding an assignment in another expression syntactically valid in the first place, not to alter an operator precedence.

Comment: I certainly hope that your professor gave you this example purely to make it clear why one should never code this way.  While the language specification gives you a clear and unambiguous answer, the fact that you have to puzzle so hard over what it does should be evidence enough that using side-effects like this in the middle of the expression is asking for trouble.  I surely hope your professor was clear about why he was sharing this terrible example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation related to machine language.

CPUs usually do not know about variables and operator precedence. They have a few registers that they can use to operate on, and memory cells to store data that exceeds their register capacity. Memory cells are numbered, and when we write `variable b`, the compiler will translate that into some memory cell's number - an address. The value stored at that addess is the value of the variable b.

But remember variables are not being calculated on - all this happens in the registers. So to add two numbers they have to be loaded into the CPU registers first.

```
int b = 9;
```

So in the above instruction the memory cell representing b is loaded with the value 9.

```
b = b + (b=3)
```

In this instruction b would get copied into a register (probably the accumulator, usually called register A) to be added with `(b=3)`. Now the value 3 is loaded into the memory cell while the register has not changed, and finally the value 3 is added to what is still in the register: the old value of b.

Hence the operation results in

```
b = 9 + 3
```

and you have the 12.

In reality the time when the registers get loaded may differ since the assignment may be a subrouting requiring to reuse the registers for other stuff. But then, to avoid side effects the registers have to be restored so the programming logic stays the same.